# Drupal 8 Error after installing simple_oauth module which failed

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, ddev

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Class 'Drupal\simple_oauth\HttpMiddleware\BasicAuthSwap' not found in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() (line 259 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php).
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'simple_oauth.http_middleware.basic_auth_swap') (Line: 173)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('simple_oauth.http_middleware.basic_auth_swap', 1) (Line: 434)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 237)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'http_middleware.session') (Line: 173)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('http_middleware.session', 1) (Line: 434)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 237)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'http_middleware.kernel_pre_handle') (Line: 173)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('http_middleware.kernel_pre_handle', 1) (Line: 434)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 237)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'http_middleware.page_cache') (Line: 173)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('http_middleware.page_cache', 1) (Line: 434)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 237)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'http_middleware.reverse_proxy') (Line: 173)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('http_middleware.reverse_proxy', 1) (Line: 434)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 237)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'http_middleware.negotiation') (Line: 173)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('http_middleware.negotiation', 1) (Line: 434)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 237)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'http_kernel') (Line: 173)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('http_kernel') (Line: 1401)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->getHttpKernel() (Line: 708)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

I tried to install a module, it had a fatal error. I can not access the website now. The module was called simple_oauth. Drush will not work as I havn't set a up a Database, atleast I dont think I have. I used ddev to set up my environment

Comment: did you use the module's installation procedure via composer ?
```composer config repositories.drupal composer https://packages.drupal.org/8 && composer require drupal/simple_oauth:^3```

Comment: yes I would get timeout everytime due to memory issue atal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Rule2Literals.php on line 53

Comment: You should probably use drush to disable the module as a first step. 

You tagged this "ddev". Did this have an out-of-memory doing the `ddev composer require` on ddev? If so, if on macOS or Windows with Hyper-V, increase the memory allocated to docker.

Comment: Thank you :@rfay and @sharklalu for the help <3

Answer (score 0):

-- Change php.ini to a higher memory limit.
Use php --ini to find the location, make sure if it has another file, memory_allocation_php.ini or similar to also edit that
change memory_limit to something like 1028M or -1 ( infinite ).